# Text Mining - Statistics Module Issue

Tags: statistics, orange

I'm using Orange Canvas for a text mining study.

This issue seems to appear once I migrated to more recent versions. When I am trying to use Statistics (from Text Mining) I can only use/add a limited number of search criteria roughly between 10 to 15. In the past I have run Statistics search with more than 20 criteria (mainly I'm using the Contains function).

In the attached picture you can see that the bottom of the search criteria functions is not going lower that middle of the frame (i.e. where the red arrow is). I tried to copy and paste some previous Statistics modules which contained more than 20 search element and that didn't work as well as the paste module didn't preserved the search elements.

Let me know if you foresee any other solution or this is a bug that somebody else met as well.

[image]

Comment: I'm not familiar with Orange but imho this feature/bug question is worth [opening an issue in the Orange repository](https://github.com/biolab/orange3/issues).